# generate sql file with file_put_contents() PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a database schema that I generate from each modules like this `$schema`:

```
Array
(
    [database] => Array
        (
            [0] => CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
                  `testid` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
                  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
                  `type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
                  `version` INT NULL ,
                  `info` TEXT NULL 
                  PRIMARY KEY (`dirname`) )
                ENGINE = InnoDB
                DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
        )

)

Array
(
    [database] => Array
        (
            [0] => CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu_test` (
                              `mid` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL ,
                              `menu_test` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
                              `name` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL ,
                              PRIMARY KEY (`mid`, `language`) )
                            ENGINE = InnoDB
                            AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
                            DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
        )

    [insert] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [table] => menu_test
                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                            [mid] => menu_admin
                            [language] => EN
                            [name] => Admin
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [table] => menu_test
                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                            [mid] => menu_seo
                            [language] => EN
                            [name] => Menu SEO
                        )

                )
```

And so on...I needed to generate an *.sql file with this schema so I tried this but it only add the last element!

```
$database = DOCUMENT_ROOT."sites/user/database.sql" ;
foreach ($schema as $type => $query) 
        {
            switch ($type)
            {
                case "database"  : 
                    foreach ($query as $sql)
                        file_put_contents($database,$sql.";");

                break ; 
                case "insert"  : 
                    foreach ($query as $sql)
                        file_put_contents($database,$sql.";");
                break ; 
            }

        }
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set.

```
  file_put_contents($database,$sql.";",FILE_APPEND); should work.
```